# how to use the enter button(key board) in php

Tags: php

For Example :

in a webpage if the user press Enter key from the keyboard a certain web button will be pressed.

Suppose there are 3 web button in a web layout namely Next,Previous,reset.
I want if the user press enter key the Next button action will be done.

if press the backspace then previous web button action will be done.

Please I want to implement this in PHP.

Full code and description.

Comment: You are going to need to use JavaScript for this, not PHP.

Comment: Okay! then please tell me how to use?

Comment: Use the `onKeyDown` event in Javascript to implement it.

Comment: you say if you press enter than run next button >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var keyPressed = e.which || evt.keyCode;
  if (keyPressed==13)
  {
    console.log(keyPressed)
    alert("your next acction")
  }
 if(keyPressed==8)
 {
    console.log(keyPressed)
    alert("Your previous action");
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is no posible with PHP. PHP is server side langue, this means the code only runs on the server not the client side. To do this you will something like javascript and jQuery.

Example in jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // enter pressed
  }
});
```

Here's a list of [key values](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by checking the keypress event in javascript.

```
$(document).on('keypress',fieldId, function(evt){ 

    var keyPressed = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    if (keyPressed == ascii value of the keyboard button) {
        // do something
    }     
});
```

The enter button value is 13.

Comment: Hi 
Can you please tell me how to implement in my problem with full code.
Please

Comment: Use jquery and add a page.
Just write the code given above in that page and include the page in your main page where you are trying to achieve this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers support an `autofocus` attribute.

```
<form action=http://google.com>
  <input value=yes type=submit autofocus>
</form>
```

This is just HTML, no PHP required, but you could echo this out.